# iOS Autolayout with multiple views with dynamic heights

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I'm trying to achieve the following:

MyViewcontroller

- MyCustomTextField (height 50)
- MyCustomTextField (height 50)
- MyCustomTextField (height 50)

Now that is easier enough in an XIB file.

However, I want to be able call something like MyCustomTextField showError:@"an error" and this to change the height (to say 80) of the related field (animated).

Can someone describe how to do this with Autolayout? My main issue is ensuring the other 'MyCustomTextField's move down at the same time, as the height of the previous field will have increased.

Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: I should mention 'MyCustomTextField' is a custom view with its own XIB file.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below approach;

1. Create IBOutlet’s for the height constraint of each textfield(your custom textfield). You can then programmatically update the constraints constant according to the text size.
2. Apply vertical spacing constraints between the textfields. So that the textfields will move with respect to their above textfields.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks I found solution. Myviewcontroller had set the height constraints on each customtextfield, which was getting in the way. I used this in my customtextfield also:
- (CGSize)intrinsicContentSize
{
    if (self.errorView.hidden) {
        return CGSizeMake(288, 53);
    } else {
        return CGSizeMake(288, 92);
    }
}

Comment: Although i found an issue with the animation. It goes to the new content size and THEN does the animation.. I want it to animate whilst applying constraints.

Comment: I just did [self.view layoutIfNeeded] in my controller - I also adjusted some of the constraints in my custom text field (have quite a few so hard to know exactly which one fixed it)

Answer (score 0):

Got working - I had constraints set for height in myviewcontroller by mistake which stopped it increasing the height.